# Buffons needle crossing both lines?

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, puzzle, pi

**Buffon's Needle Problem** : Given a needle of length $l$ dropped on a plane ruled with parallel lines $t$ units apart, what is the probability that the needle will cross a line?

I am working out problems with  Buffon's needle in varying lengths. 
 **Case A:** Given a needle of length $7$, and lines spaced $4$ units apart, what is the probability that the needle crosses both the lines when dropped? 
 **Case B:** What if the needle of length $h$ and distance between lines $L$ was $2L < h <= 3L$, what is the probability of the needle crossing all three lines ?
Give the general formula of probability for both cases. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For referencing purposes, this is part of Problems Plus 8.12 of Stewart's Calculus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll use the variable names in your first sentence: $l$ is the needle length, and $t$ is the gap between lines.

Also, let random variables $\theta$ be the angle from the "positive $x$-axis" to the needle and $Y$ be the distance from the leftmost endpoint of the needle to the closest line to the left of that endpoint.

[image: Buffon's Needle]

By symmetry of the needle either "pointing up" or "pointing down", we can assume $\theta$ is not negative. So we have $0\lt\theta\leq \pi/2\;$ and $0\lt Y\leq t$.

These two r.v.'s are independent and uniformly distributed. So their joint density function is $f_{\theta,Y}(\theta,y) = \dfrac{2}{\pi t}$.

(a) Here we assume $t\leq l\leq 2t$. Define event $C = $ "Needle crosses two lines". Event $C$ is only possible in the range $0\lt\theta\lt\cos^{-1}(t/l)$. For any $\theta$ in this range, $C$ occurs exactly when $2t-l\cos\theta\lt Y\lt t$. Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(C) &=& \int_{\theta=0}^{\cos^{-1}(t/l)} \int_{y=2t-l\cos\theta}^{t} f_{\theta,Y}(\theta,y) \;dy\;d\theta \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\pi t}\int_{0}^{\cos^{-1}(t/l)} (l\cos\theta - t) \;d\theta \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\pi t} \bigg[l\sin\theta - t\theta\bigg]_{0}^{\cos^{-1}(t/l)} \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\pi t} \left[\sqrt{l^2-t^2} - t\cos^{-1}(t/l)\right]. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

$$\\$$

(b) Similar working to above but here the assumption is that $2t\leq l\leq 3t$. Define event $C = $ "Needle crosses three lines". Event $C$ is only possible in the range $0\lt\theta\lt\cos^{-1}(2t/l)$. For any $\theta$ in this range, $C$ occurs exactly when $3t-l\cos\theta\lt Y\lt t$. Therefore,

\begin{eqnarray*}
P(C) &=& \int_{\theta=0}^{\cos^{-1}(2t/l)} \int_{y=3t-l\cos\theta}^{t} f_{\theta,Y}(\theta,y) \;dy\;d\theta \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\pi t}\int_{0}^{\cos^{-1}(2t/l)} (l\cos\theta - 2t) \;d\theta \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\pi t} \bigg[l\sin\theta - 2t\theta\bigg]_{0}^{\cos^{-1}(2t/l)} \\
&=& \dfrac{2}{\pi t} \left[\sqrt{l^2-4t^2} - 2t\cos^{-1}(2t/l)\right]. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thank you, I really appreciate the help!